# ZigZag tree travesal

Tags: c#, tree, interview-questions

The question is taken for a coding interview I had, it is also in geeks for geeks,  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zigzag-tree-traversal/

you are given a binary tree and you need to print it in a ZigZag/Snake order
for level one from left to right and the next level from right to left and so on.

I was asked only to come up with a solution I used a queue and a stack in the real interview, when I coded it now I tried using 2 stacks.

Please review the code as if it was a real interview, complexity, coding style, assume I have 20-30 minutes to code. you can ignore the test case.

Thanks.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TreeQuestions
{
    [TestClass]
    public class PrintBinaryTreeZigZag
    {

        [TestMethod]
        public void PrintBinaryTreeZigZagTest()
        {
            BinaryTree root = new BinaryTree
            {
                Value = 1,
                Left = new BinaryTree { Value = 2 },
                Right = new BinaryTree { Value = 3 }
            };
            root.Left.Left = new BinaryTree { Value = 7 };
            root.Left.Right = new BinaryTree { Value = 6 };
            root.Right.Left = new BinaryTree { Value = 5 };
            root.Right.Right = new BinaryTree { Value = 4 };
            List<int> res = PrintBinaryZigZag(root);
            List<int> expected = new List<int> { 1, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4 };
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, res);

        }

        public List<int> PrintBinaryZigZag(BinaryTree root)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            Stack<BinaryTree> currentLevel = new Stack<BinaryTree>();
            Stack<BinaryTree> nextLevel = new Stack<BinaryTree>();
            List<int> result = new List<int>();
            currentLevel.Push(root);
            bool leftToRight = true;
            while (currentLevel.Count > 0)
            {
                BinaryTree temp = currentLevel.Peek();
                currentLevel.Pop();
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    //same as print
                    result.Add(temp.Value);

                    if (leftToRight)
                    {
                        if (temp.Left != null)
                        {
                            nextLevel.Push(temp.Left);
                        }
                        if (temp.Right != null)
                        {
                            nextLevel.Push(temp.Right);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (temp.Right != null)
                        {
                            nextLevel.Push(temp.Right);
                        }
                        if (temp.Left != null)
                        {
                            nextLevel.Push(temp.Left);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (currentLevel.Count == 0)
                {
                    leftToRight = !leftToRight;
                    Stack<BinaryTree> tempStack = currentLevel;
                    currentLevel = nextLevel;
                    nextLevel = tempStack;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    public class BinaryTree
    {
        public BinaryTree Left { get; set; }
        public BinaryTree Right { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: An example of input/output in a clearer format that a test case would be great to understand the context of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm seems okay so I'll review the OOP aspect.

### Naming

1. The method named `PrintBinaryZigZag` but it doesn't print anything.
2. The class named `BinaryTree` isn't really a binary tree, it's more of a `Node`.

### Implementations vs interfaces

You return `List<int>`, but do you really need a list?

The goal of this method if to return a list that represents a binary tree.

Should you be able to add/remove objects from this list? Do you need the indexer, that is specific to the list? I don't think so. In this case, return `IEnumerable<int>`.

### C# details

```
BinaryTree temp = currentLevel.Peek();
currentLevel.Pop();
```

You could simply do : `BinaryTree temp = currentLevel.Pop();`

### Flow

```
if (leftToRight)
{
    if (temp.Left != null)
    {
        nextLevel.Push(temp.Left);
    }
    if (temp.Right != null)
    {
        nextLevel.Push(temp.Right);
    }
}
else
{
    if (temp.Right != null)
    {
        nextLevel.Push(temp.Right);
    }
    if (temp.Left != null)
    {
        nextLevel.Push(temp.Left);
    }
}
```

I'm *sure* there's a way to make this smaller. Now, this is a take to maybe give you an idea, I don't think it's perfect, it's weird to use a `foreach` when you only have two elements in the list. But maybe if can give you an idea to make this code smaller.

```
var orderedNodes = leftToRight ? new []{ temp.Left, temp.Right } : new []{ temp.Right, temp.Left };

foreach(var node in orderedNodes.Where(n => n != null)) 
{
    nextLevel.Push(node);
}
```

This :

```
if (currentLevel.Count == 0)
{
    leftToRight = !leftToRight;
    Stack<BinaryTree> tempStack = currentLevel;
    currentLevel = nextLevel;
    nextLevel = tempStack;
}
```

I think it could be outside your `while` loop.

Comment: thanks! the last part needs to be inside the while loop otherwise you do now switch the stacks, you have 2 of those.